# How to extract Eddystone UUID(Namspace and Instance ID) from 'Message'

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone, google-nearby

I have subscribed for BLE device using Nearby.Messages.subscribe method.I will get a callback on MessageListener's onFound(Message message) method.But how to extract  Eddystone  UUID(Namspace and Instance ID)  from Message object

Answer (score 0):

See Nearby Messages documentation here https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/advanced#ble_beacon_ids

Comment: Thankyou Tony, In the document they have mentioned that to fetch Eddystone UUID you need to add MessageFilter and you have to define EDDYSTONE_UID_NAMESPACE.Is there any other method with out mentioning  EDDYSTONE_UID_NAMESPACE.Because i could see the Eddystone UUID without  MessageFilter  in the Message object.

Comment: To answer your original question, does the following work?

EddystoneUid eddystoneUid = EddystoneUid.from(message);